# Math.round() Method in Java

Tags: java, rounding

`Math.round(4816.5)` is returning 4817.

I want to round up only if decimal is >5 and not >=5. So here, I need result as 4816.

Please give me solutions.

Answer (score 6):

`Math.round(n)` is basically the same as `(long) Math.floor(n + 0.5)` so you can just modify that algorithm slightly:

```
long rounded = (long) Math.ceil(n - 0.5);
```

Comment: Make sure you preserve the type. (change 0.5 to 0.5f)

Answer (score 5):

Use a double negative:

```
-Math.round(-n)
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a RoundingMode of **HALF_DOWN** and let Java take care of the rest:

```
        BigDecimal value = new BigDecimal(4816.5);
        value = value.setScale(0, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
        long result = value.longValue();
        System.out.println(result);
```